# vlookup #n/a when cross referencing data

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've been reading every article I can on VLOOKUP to troubleshoot my problem, but nothing is working, and I'm getting frustrated.

This is a small snippet of a massive amount of data I need to extrapolate.

Our data: Column 1 is flight#, 2 is City of origin, column 4 indicates whether it is a first class or business class.

```
11  MSP SLC 000-012-114
12  MSP LHR 000-040-206
40  JFK ATH 000-034-259
42  MIA JFK 000-012-098
```

Clients data:

```
11  MSP 1721    Business(12)
11  MSP 1721    Main Cabin(114)
11  MSP 1721    Common(126)
54  IAH 1800    Business(12)
54  IAH 1800    Common(126)
```

My goal is to cross reference the flight# to the class of the flight to make sure our data matches the clients data.

What Ive done:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,CLIENT!$A$928,4,FALSE)
```

A2 is the 11 below, CLIENT!$A$928 is the table of the client's data, 4 is the column of the class.  I cannot figure out why I keep getting #N/A

```
11  MSP #N/A    
54  IAH #N/A    
188 DTW #N/A    
189 BOS #N/A    
437 JFK #N/A    
438 JFK #N/A    
522 SLC #N/A    
557 DTW #N/A    
561 BOS #N/A    
697 SLC #N/A    
780 DFW #N/A    
781 MSP #N/A    
788 SLC #N/A
```

Comment: ▲ Agreed. That should be a `#REF!` error, not a `#N/A`.

Comment: Yes!! I just needed to play around with it.  I did figure it out.  Thank you so much for the help!  :)